# Count the number of binary representations that have the given number of occurrences.

Tags: combinatorics, binary

How many binary representation exists that each has five "00", three "01", three "10" and three "11" in it ?!

Comment: Do you allow parts of those patterns to be used more than once? Do you count $001$ as having one $00$ and one $01$?

Comment: Yes, 001 will count as 00 and 01 at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See in the given problem that you can only have 3 '01' and 3 '10' meaning that you have to change the sequence of a binary string 3 times. For example in the binary represantation 11111011101101 I have changed the string a total of 4 times and got the  abovementioned requirments. Now we can view this problem as more of a stars and bars problem. We can distribute the 5 '00's into the three strings of zeroes ie which would give us these combinations for strings:(A string signifies a series of a single number for example 111111111 is a string of ones)

{1,1,3} - 3 cases

{2,2,1} - 3 cases

{0,1,4} - 6 cases

{0,0,5} - 3 cases

{3,2,0} - 6 cases

Now similarly for 1 we have 4 strings and 3 '11's.

{0,2,1,0} - 12 cases   (0 signifies there is only one '1' in that string and the pair does not form)

{1,1,1,0} - 4 cases

{0,0,3,0} - 4 cases

Notice that each case case gives a unique representation

Now we just have to multiply the 0 cases by 1 cases and add them all

$3*20+3*20+3*20+6*20+6*20$
=420

Hope this helps:)

Comment: It helped a lot, thanks! 
But two things that I want to make sure of is that;
1. You considered your block of 1's and 0's like this : 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
Shouldn't we count 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 as well ?!
2. Why didn't you count the combination {3, 2, 0} in the 0 cases ?

Comment: Firstly yes I forgot about that case and I will be editing that into my answer and secondly in a binary sequence you can only start the sequence by a 1 otherwise the 0 hold no value.

Comment: Additionally I have went into a little bit more in detail explanation in my answer by writing all the cases down but we can directly apply stars and bars in both 1 and 0 cases. In 1 we will get 20 solutions and in 0 we will get 21 solutions.By multiplying both you have the answer directly which is 420

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really appreciate your time and effort :).